# How can ı do accordion menu toggle icon?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Im trying to implement accordion menu. I did that and it's not working. I just want to do toggle icon

```js
            $('.logo-button').click(function(){
            $(this).find('.my-arrow').toggleClass('down');
        });
```

```css
.my-arrow.down {
        transform:rotate(450deg);}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#logo-fifthteen-content" class="logo-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse15" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse15">
                                            <span class="left-side-panel">Text</span>
                                            <i class="fa fa-angle-right my-arrow"></i>
                                        </a>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You should provide any error you are getting. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the `transform` property to work, try to set `display: block` or `display:inline-block` within the `.my-arrow.down` class:

```
.my-arrow.down {
    display: block;
    transform:rotate(450deg);
    ...
```

You also need to include content within your `<i>` element. For example, you could use the `>` character:

```
<i class="fa fa-angle-right my-arrow">
     >
</i>
```

Here is a working example with your code and my modifications:

```js
$('.logo-button').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.my-arrow').toggleClass('down');
});
```

```css
.my-arrow.down {
    display: inline-block;
    transform:rotate(450deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#logo-fifthteen-content" class="logo-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse15" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse15">
<span class="left-side-panel">Text</span>
<i class="fa fa-angle-right my-arrow">></i>
</a>
```

Comment: When I click on 'text' the 'down' class does not appear
@terminalvelocity

Comment: @Emre, the 'text' element is inside the `<span>` and is NOT the intended clickable element. The `<i>` element has the class `my-arrow` and is the intended clickable element. Just add text to the `<i>` element like this                                            `<i class="fa fa-angle-right my-arrow"> CLICK THIS </i>`

Comment: Sorry I misrepresented. When ı click "<a href="#logo-fifthteen-content" class="logo-button"....>"

Comment: @Emre, if you'd like the `<a>` element to be the button, you need to add the `my-arrow` class to it resulting in `<a ...  class="logo-button my-arrow" ... </a>`

Comment: I gave my-arrow class to svg element ı just want to do toggle icon